# Проблемы со стилями на Яндекс Браузере

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, яндекс-браузер

друзья! 
Мой вопрос будет несколько абстрактный. В последнее время иногда встречаюсь с проблемным отображением стилей CSS на Яндекс Браузере. То фоновое изображение пропадает, то просто все элементы начинают перемешиваться. 
Есть ли какие особенности кроссбраузерности, касающиеся конкретно Яндекс Браузера? Конкретной информации в сети почти нет, поэтому интересуюсь у более опытных товарищей :) 
Если у вас есть какая-то информация или ссылки на нее, будьте так добры, поделитесь! 
Заранее спасибо :)

Пример кода, в котором пропадают фоновые изображения иконок преимуществ

```
<div class="features_main">
    <div class="feature_main">
        <p>Преимущество №1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="feature_main">
        <p>Преимущество №2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="feature_main">
        <p>Преимущество №3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="feature_main">
        <p>Преимущество №4</p>
    </div>
</div> 





.feature_main {
    margin-top: 70px;
    background-image: url(../img/advantage.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
}

.feature_main p {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-family: "DinProRegular";
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: приложите пример кода, который неправильно отображается

Comment: @Alex добавил код

Comment: возможно путь не правильно отработан... для теста введите полный путь к картинке, а не относительный...

Comment: @Alex подскажите, пожалуйста, как выглядит полный путь?

Comment: @ИгорьВойнов если css находится по адресу site.com/themes/css то при ../img/advantage.png , файл должен быть расположен по адресу site.com/themes/img/advantage.png попробуйте так и указать...